# How to get coordinates where pointing a mouse with raycast in 3D?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I have a player3D node and I want move it to mouse coordinates. I found the code that can to get that coordinates, but it was on godot 3.2 and it doesn't work now. Then I found a way how it works in godot 4, but I have a problem with this code now:

```
extends Node3D

func ScreenPointToRay():
    var spaceState = get_world_3d().direct_space_state
    var mousePos = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
    var camera = get_tree().root.get_camera_3d()
    
    var rayOrigin = camera.project_ray_origin(mousePos)
    var rayEnd = rayOrigin + camera.project_ray_normal(mousePos) * 200
    var params = PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(rayOrigin, rayEnd)
    print("params = ",params)
    
    var rayArray = spaceState.intersect_ray(params)
    print("summary = ",rayArray)
    
    if rayArray.has("position"):
        return rayArray["position"]
    return Vector3()

func _process(delta):
    var loca = Vector3i(0,0,0)
    var motion:Vector3
    
    motion = ScreenPointToRay()
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("L_Click"):
        motion = ScreenPointToRay()
        print(motion)
        loca.y = 0
        loca.x = snappedf(motion.x, 2)
        loca.z = snappedf(motion.z, 2)
        
        get_child(0).move_and_collide(loca)
```

The `ScreenPointToRay()` function returns Vector3(0,0,0), and in the variables I have this:
[image: params = <PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D#-9223371957263661755> summary = { }]

I don't know how, but very rarely I get a noraml parameters in `RayArray`.

Comment: I can only guess the ray is not intersecting any physic bodies.

Comment: When you said that, I've check my meshes and found out that it with warning. It seems collisionShape3D doesn't work with MeshInstance3D.

Answer (score 1):

I tested out your code and the ScreenPointToRay() logic all seems to be correct. Have you checked that the object(s) you are raycasting against (floor, terrain, etc.) have a node that can detect collision (ex. StaticBody3D, Area3D, etc.)

Your ScreenPointToRay() function is likely returning Vector3(0,0,0) because there are no colliders in the scene for the raycast to hit, so it is returning an empty Vector3.

Note: If the object(s) you are raycasting against is an Area3D, you will need collide_with_areas to be set to true for the PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D, so you would need to change:

```
var params = PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(rayOrigin, rayEnd)
```

to:

```
var params = PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(rayOrigin, rayEnd)
params.collide_with_areas = true
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: You are a saviour! Have been struggling with this. As soon as I removed my staticbody and replaced it with a Area3D it started giving random values because of non collision. And as soon as I enabled collide_with_areas it started working again! This should be accepted as the right answer!